# How to deactivate all objects in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

How to deactivate all objects in Fabric.js before saving an image?

```
function rasterize() {
  if (!myscript.Canvas.supports('toDataURL')) {
    alert('This browser doesn\'t provide means to serialize canvas to an image');
  }
  else {
    /*i want to deactivate all object here*/
    window.open(canvas.toDataURL('png'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

`canvas.deactivateAll();` => no events are fired
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#deactivateAll

**or**

`canvas.deactivateAllWithDispatch();` => if activeObject exists the events 'before:selection:cleared' and 'selection:cleared' are fired.
http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#deactivateAllWithDispatch

Comment: @kienz Is there a reason why "canvas.renderAll()" should be fired manually after "deactivateAll()" ? I'd expect it to be automatic.

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me (fabric 2.7):

```
this.canvas.forEachObject(object => {
    object.selectable = false;
    object.evented = false;
});
```

---

Another solution is to apply some **CSS** to the canvas : `pointer-events: none`

Answer (score 1):

```
canvas.deactivateAll();
canvas.renderAll();
```

only this two lines also do the same no need to make canvas.selection as false. It is used to disable group selection.

Answer (score 1):

that's work for me:

```
canvas.discardActiveObject();
canvas.requestRenderAll();
```

Comment: This seems to be an answer. Maybe not too explanatory, but not a comment. The other answer mentioning `discardActiveObject` looks more like something that should have been a comment.

Comment: Please add supporting details to your answer to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

When I found this question, I was looking for:

```
/* Make sure that touch / click events do nothing */
canvas.deactivateAll();
canvas.selection = false;
canvas.forEachObject(function(o) {
    o.selectable = false;
});
```